# Fix @android:id/empty behavoir in ListFragment

Tags: android-listfragment, simplecursoradapter, onpause

I'm using a cursor in a ListFragment with Views ListView @android:id/list and TextView @andoid:id/empty. Now, since a non closed cursor uses more akku performance, i want to close the cursor when i start a new activity. i put cursor.close() in onPause() of the ListFragment.

The problem is, when the cursor is closed, the TextView is shown for a short time before the new activity is getting started. This looks ugly and causes a short delay before.

Ive tried something like this:

```
if (cursor.moveToNext()){
        tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

But this didnt change anything. Even if the shown textview is gone, the delay would stay i guess...

Do u guys have a good way for me to solve the problem?

thanks in advance

pebbles

---

My Cursor:

```
 public void loadCursor(){
    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ProgressContentUri, new String[]{Table.Columns._ID, Table.Columns.NAME, Table.Columns.DATE}, "", null, Table.Columns.DATE+ " DESC");        
}
```

Comment: How do you get your cursor ? From a cursor loader ?

Comment: From contextProvider, i posted the cursor in topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to close it in the onStop method of your fragment, or use a [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) which is a much better way to use cursors.

This way the cursor will be loaded asynchronously and closed automatically.

Comment: thank you. ill read into the CursorLoader and try it the comin days!